# Moving a Symfony project from a server with CPanel to Wamp

Tags: php, symfony1, cpanel

I'm having problems with Symfony. I recently got a Symfony project and I'm having problems moving a Symfony project from a server with Cpanel to a virtual server on Wamp. I haven't used Symfony before so I'm really confused on how the whole project would be opened in like a tree structure so that i can see whats going on.

Comment: What are the problems? cPanel shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not a Symfony project will work on your server -- it depends on the server configuration.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on how to move the project since its not a project i made. I also haven't used Symfony until now so I'm not exactly sure on what i would need to move either manually or with some type of IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's file structure is as such:

```
apps/
  frontend/
  backend/
batch/
cache/
config/
data/
  sql/
doc/
lib/
  model/
log/
plugins/
test/
  unit/
  functional/
web/
  css/
  images/
  js/
  uploads/
```

I presume you do not have access to the repository so you'll have to copy all the files to your WAMP installation. Generally you do not need to copy over the cache/* and log/* files. After copying the whole project to WAMP you can see if it's still working by running `./symfony.bat` or `./symfony` on linux/unix/osx.

Best way to copy the whole project is by creating an archive first, then extract it into your WAMP installation. In order to create tar.gz/zip/rar/tar.bz backups follow these steps:

1. Log in your cPanel and go to the File Manager;
2. In the left box, navigate to the directory / files you'd like to archive. Mark the items to be archived in the left box and choose "Compress" from the top menu